# Windows 7 Boot Camp Automatic Brightness

Tags: bootcamp, windows

Is it possible to enable automatic brightness on my MacBook when I use Windows 7 ?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Control Panel → Hardware & Sound → Power Options → Change Plan Settings → Change advanced power settings → Display → Enable adaptive brightness and switch it on for On battery and Plugged in.

Comment: It's enabled but it did'nt seem to work :(